# Stopping a jQuery event function from

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I posted a question yesterday which was answered, sadly though I now have a new issue with the said code and am looking for some kind soul to point me in the right direction so I can learn how to get the issues fixed so I dont need to ask for help in the issue again.

Here is the jsfiddle link to the script http://jsfiddle.net/EzYeH/10/

What I am trying to achieve is to stop the event function **expand** initialising if the event function **shrink** is still running.

I have tried using and reading up on `.stopPropagation()` & `.stop()` but cannot get the implementation correct.

Thanks in advance anyone who can tackle this,

Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/EzYeH/13/ for updated code:

A couple of issues: your `$this` variable was implicitly global, which was causing layout problems.

You were not determining the current state to let you figure out whether an expand or shrink was appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was only expecting an insight into how the code works but am very grateful you have also shared the working code with me. Also thank you for pointing out the flaws in the $this var and also fixing.